# Red dot on Close Votes review queue but the queue was cleared (Bug)

Tags: bug

> [image]

Bug or as designed?  If this actually IS a bug, can this be fixed?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

This error was corrected by the system:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Err, no? This just means the queue has now been cleared. The bug still remains tagged [status-review] on the Meta SE question I linked in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue, currently under [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). See this question on Meta SE: [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302093/313042)